# Como criar um vetor a partir de outro no r?

Tags: r

Preciso criar o vetor `fixo` de `NA` e `0` partir de outro vetor `coef`.
Se

```
coef<-c(1,4,10)
```

então

```
fixo = (NA,0,0,NA,0,0,0,0,0,NA)
```

Tentei usar `str_detect`:

```
num<-c(1,4,10)
maiorn <- max(num)
A<-seq(1:maiorn)

for (i in 1:maiorn) {
  ifelse(str_detect(A[i], num),
         A[i]<-"NA",
         A[i]<-0)
}
```

Mas não funcionou. O `str_detect` só encontra strings. Tem alguma função como contido ou outra forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outra maneira é com a função `is.na<-`. E para criar o vetor `fixo` usei a função `numeric`, mais a [ideia do Willian Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349995/como-criar-um-vetor-a-partir-de-outro-no-r/350012#350012) de obter o comprimento de `fixo` com `max(coef)`.

```
coef <- c(1, 4, 10)
fixo <- numeric(max(coef))

is.na(fixo) <- coef

fixo
#[1] NA  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0 NA
```

Comment: excelente, muito elegante.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar o vetor `coef` para indexar os elementos do vetor `fixo`:

```
coef <- c(1,4,10)

# criar vetor de zeros
fixo <- rep(0, max(coef))

# adicionar NA para cada coef
fixo[coef] <- NA

fixo
# [1] NA  0  0 NA  0  0  0  0  0 NA
```

Comment: excelente, muito elegante.